# Why MySQL adds extra digits to floats?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of prices.
Each price is a FLOAT with two digits after the dot.
From some reason, when I use the price in IF expression, the result is the same float with many additional digits:

```
mysql> select price, IF(1, price,0) as my_price from tbl_prices limit 10;
+-------+------------------+
| price | my_price         |
+-------+------------------+
| 79.95 | 79.9499969482422 |
| 99.95 | 99.9499969482422 |
| 89.95 | 89.9499969482422 |
| 89.95 | 89.9499969482422 |
| 79.95 | 79.9499969482422 |
| 89.95 | 89.9499969482422 |
| 89.95 | 89.9499969482422 |
| 79.95 | 79.9499969482422 |
| 79.95 | 79.9499969482422 |
| 69.95 | 69.9499969482422 |
+-------+------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, **price** looks good, however the result of IF expression that returns the same **price** contains garbage.

Does anybody know what is the reason for this garbage, and how can I get rid of it (without using ROUND)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just don't. A float is not an exact value. Use DECIMAL fields for example for a price.

Comment: I second this.  DO NOT use float for precise decimal values, as many of them cannot be faithfully represented in binary.  Decimal works around this by using a different storage mechanism with exact semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't represent the .95 in floating point. This is the closest you will get. This is why float is approximate.

If you want exact decimal places, use DECIMAL

Answer (score 2):

At first you should know how the [floating point works](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Fortunately mysql provides [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html) data type, which can specify exact precision, for example:

```
DECIMAL( 10, 2)
```

Will store 10 decimal places long number and 2 digits out of that on right side, for example:

```
12345678.12
       1.03
```

and so on.